# Template hierarchy for post format in a custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, post-format

I'm trying to override the post format taxonomy/archive page for videos and images for posts of type "gallery" (for example), but I'm not sure if I'm doing the right thing.

I've gotten the page to show up correctly with a URL like this 
`/gallery?post_format=video` , but I can't override the template for it, I've only been able to get `taxonomy-post-format_post-format-video` to work, but I don't want to override the templates for that, I just want to do it for those under the custom post type `gallery`.

I'm really not sure if I should be using categories/post types for this, if it will be easier. My goal is just to have a gallery page with just videos, and another gallery page of just images, I wanted to make use of WP's inbuilt post formats, but I'm not sure how to move on from here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it isn't entirely possible or correct to force WP to do something it wasn't prepared to do, so I set up a taxonomy for my custom post type and rewrote the slugs so I could get /gallery/videos and gallery/images as archive pages that I can modify.